# android error Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error

Tags: android-emulator

I am create android application.
In application arise one error arise like Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
So I will do the following step.
          Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 1.5). click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK

But can't solve the problem
So please give me another solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 7 Solution if you are using proguard to obfuscate your code:**

Confirmed the problem is caused by ProGuard command line in the file
[Android SDK Installation Directory]\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat

Edit the following line will solve the problem:

```
call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
```

to

```
call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```